# Java Access DB Connection

Tags: java, database-connection, jdbc-odbc

I try to make project with connection to db (MS Access 2010)
I use this tutorial [on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35018/Access-MS-Access-Databases-from-Java).

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DbAccess
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String database = 
              "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=myDB.mdb;";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
            Statement s = conn.createStatement();

            // create a table
            String tableName = "myTable" + String.valueOf((int)(Math.random() * 1000.0));
            String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + 
                                 " (id Integer, name Text(32))";
            s.execute(createTable); 

            // enter value into table
            for(int i=0; i<25; i++)
            {
              String addRow = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES ( " + 
                     String.valueOf((int) (Math.random() * 32767)) + ", 'Text Value " + 
                     String.valueOf(Math.random()) + "')";
              s.execute(addRow);
            }

            // Fetch table
            String selTable = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
            s.execute(selTable);
            ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
            while((rs!=null) && (rs.next()))
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + " : " + rs.getString(2));
            }

            // drop the table
            String dropTable = "DROP TABLE " + tableName;
            s.execute(dropTable);

            // close and cleanup
            s.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But i get strange Exception : java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][????????? ????????? ODBC] ???????? ?????? ?? ?????? ? ?? ?????? ???????, ???????????? ?? ?????????

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][????????? ????????? ODBC] ????????
>   ?????? ?? ?????? ? ?? ?????? ???????, ???????????? ?? ????????? at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956) at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113) at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(JdbcOdbc.java:3072) at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:323)
>   at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:174) at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579) at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221) at
>   dbaccess.DbAccess.main(DbAccess.java:28)

I google it and find other questions on Stack like this : [Stack Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893262/java-sql-sqlexception-microsoftodbc-microsoft-access-driver)

So i add all ODBC drivers that can help me connect *.mdb file. But nothing good hepend.(

What is it and how connect to Access DB?

Comment: Your error message consists of question marks?

Comment: yes. so i don't know in what exactly is error, but Google give me many posts like "java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Comment: please share the code and the stack trace.

Comment: what is the DNS name?

Comment: @user2511414 DNS or DSN?

Comment: @user2511414 i added User DSN : Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb,*.accdb), Driver do Microsoft Access(*.mdb), MS Access Database(*.mdb, *.accdb), Microsoft Access-Treiber(*.mdb)

Comment: sorry type, so the question is why dont you map the file with a unique DSN name in OS?! and just point it out simple with `jdbc:odbc:mydsn` ?!, and are you sure MS Jet is installed? usually it's installed by office product.

Comment: MS Jet is installed because i use it with C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing fundamentally wrong with your code because I pasted it into Eclipse and it ran fine. The only change I made was to specify the path to the database file, i.e., instead of using

```
DBQ=myDB.mdb
```

I used

```
DBQ=C:\\__tmp\\myDB.mdb
```

I was also running it under a 32-bit JVM (on a 32-bit computer). So, my suggestions would be

1. Try specifying the complete path to the `.mdb` file like I did.
2. If you still get an error, check your Java environment to see if your application is running in a 64-bit JVM. If it is, then `Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}` will not work: there is no 64-bit version of the older Jet ODBC driver. In that case you have two options:

   i. Configure your application to run in a 32-bit JVM, or

   ii. Download and install the 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255), and then use `Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, firsly - i chanded path, but it didn't help.. And a question - how i can configure my app to 32 JVM? because i use 32-bit MS Office and installing of x64 Access Database Engine is imposible as i try

Comment: @user2167382 Which IDE are you using?

Comment: well, i found solution here [link](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic45491.html) about configuration, so thank you)

Comment: Answer still relevant!  Didn't even occur to me that Eclipse was pointing to a 64-bit version of Java, and the command line was using a 32-bit version (corporate environment - no options).  The error I was getting about not being able to find the name or driver never even clued me in on the Java version.  Just configuring Eclipse to point to the 32-bit version fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Now that the JDBC-ODBC Bridge has been removed from Java 8 a better approach would be to use the [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver. For more information see

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)